# what do the numbers and letters mean that succed mem

Tags: bash, kernel

what do the numbers and letters represent?

```
lshw mem: b2400000-b240ffff
```

im trying to familiries my self with linux abit more and w\s wondering what the 8 letters and numbers mean after i

lshw list all hardware command

in bash konsole i get a run down of details and then the numbers what are these numbers and letters?

Any books or references videos, documentation would help me thanks with where i am

Comment: It's a hexidecimal notation of a location in memory.

Comment: `lshw -C network` will also show this but with a bit more information. It will show "resources irq {irq}" and then those 2 memory addresses. Resources is explained here: https://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter#Resources

Comment: @karel ok i do understand but what makes this any different// code///         PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x93736000-0x937befff] (561152 bytes)???                                                                                                                                       this is part of a kern.log

Comment: or should i say what is meant by the 0x